# NPM install fails due to stream-mmmagic

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am using npm module named`"stream-mmmagic": "^2.1.0"`in my package.json, When I am running npm install. I am getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mmmagic@0.5.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mmmagic@0.5.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

At present, I am using these versions

```
node version is 10.15.1

python version is 2.7.17

nvm running version is 1.1.7
```

How to fix the above error, Please help me resolve the error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at the referenced log?

Comment: yes @DaveNewton, but not able to figure out

Comment: I guess even the logs look like the error message in terminal

Comment: But you don't show the actual error(s). Might be helpful to include the actual information.

Comment: In terminal also and in log file also, I am getting same above error, which I mentioned above @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0):

This looks like to be a generic installation error, which you can find multiple solutions in this [Github issue page](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809), I would recommend a good look through the comments, and let us know when you found the solution.